# Having puppet use yum --installroot for certain nodes

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

I have a case where we are throwing together diskless node images that get thrown out to nodes via PXE and then mounted via a ramdisk.  To build these previously we have just installed packages with yum --installroot= install .

I was wondering though if I were able to have puppet instead of doing a regular yum -y install  that for some node types would instead follow this pattern and do yum --installroot= install .

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be doable with `install_options` (which, for the `yum` provider, requires Puppet 3.6 or newer):

```
package { 'somepackage':
  ensure          => present,
  install_options => [ '--installroot=' ],
}
```

Comment: That's much better than the alternative of writing a new provider type and calling it conditionally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and even in proper puppet community format!